# i working on django application to charge a user before posting his products. i want to offer a free option, how to archive this and save add with sti

Tags: django, stripe-payments, payment

i am working on django application where admin can set pricing,and give coupon, my proble is how to offer a free option or free listing whe you are using stripe.

this is a function on my views.py

```py
`@login_required(login_url='/users/login')
def create_ad_func(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":

        data = dict(request.POST)
        data = clean(data)
        ad = AdList.objects.create_ad(**data)
        img_counter = 0
        img_files = request.FILES

        if len(request.FILES) > 0:
            for ad_img in request.FILES:
                print(img_files[ad_img])
                upload_img(ad_img, img_files, ad)
        else:
            url = upload_image(request.FILES[ad_img], ad.id, img_counter)
            img_counter = img_counter + 1
            data[ad_img] = url
            
        date_time = arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        data['post_date'] = date_time
        pprint(data)
        AdList.objects.filter(pk=ad.id).update(**data)
        objectss = AdList.objects.filter(pk=ad.id)

        subscription_list = ['urgent_ad', 'regular_ad', 'featured_ad']

        for key in data.keys():
            if key in subscription_list:
                    ad_subscription = AdSubscription.objects.values()[0]
                    price = ad_subscription[key]
                    charge = ad_subscription[key] * 100
                    print(price, charge)
        
        key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        

        return render(request, 'checkout.html', {"user": request.user, 'ad': ad, 'price':price, 'key':key, 'charge':charge})
    else:
        ad_subscription = AdSubscription.objects.values()[0]
        return render(request, 'ad-list-cat.html', {"user": request.user, "subscription": ad_subscription})



and this is my manage.py
```

```python
class AdListManager(BaseUserManager):
        """
        Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
        for authentication instead of usernames.
        """

        def create_ad(self, **data):
            """
            Create and save a User with the given email and password.
            """
            email = data["email"]
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            ad = self.model(**data)
            ad.save()
            message="your ad was published successiful"
            return ad,message

        def update_ad(self, pk, data):
            pprint(data)
            self.model.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(**data)

        def list_ads(self, email):
            return self.model.objects.filter(email=email)
```

i tried to modify so that if the value is les than <5 charge 0 but problem is that stripe do not accepte zero charge.
this is what i tried.

```py
@login_required(login_url='/users/login')
def create_ad_func(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":

        data = dict(request.POST)
        data = clean(data)
        ad = AdList.objects.create_ad(**data)
        img_counter = 0
        img_files = request.FILES

        if len(request.FILES) > 0:
            for ad_img in request.FILES:
                print(img_files[ad_img])
                upload_img(ad_img, img_files, ad)
        else:
            url = upload_image(request.FILES[ad_img], ad.id, img_counter)
            img_counter = img_counter + 1
            data[ad_img] = url
            
        date_time = arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        data['post_date'] = date_time
        pprint(data)
        AdList.objects.filter(pk=ad.id).update(**data)
        objectss = AdList.objects.filter(pk=ad.id)

        subscription_list = ['urgent_ad', 'regular_ad', 'featured_ad']

        for key in data.keys():
            if key in subscription_list:
                ad_subscription = AdSubscription.objects.values()[0]
                if ad_subscription[key] < 5:
                    # save the subscription without charging with stripe
                    ad.subscriptions.create(
                        items=[{
                            'price': 'price_id',
                            'quantity': 1,
                        }],
                        expand=['latest_invoice.payment_intent']
                    )
                    price = 0
                    charge = 0
                else:
                    price = ad_subscription[key]
                    charge = ad_subscription[key] * 100

        key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY

        return render(request, 'checkout.html', {"user": request.user, 'ad': ad, 'price':price, 'key':key, 'charge':charge})
    else:
        ad_subscription = AdSubscription.objects.values()[0]
        return render(request, 'ad-list-cat.html', {"user": request.user, "subscription": ad_subscription})
```

any help to archive an option of adding a free listing option while using stripe?`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to offer a free trial for you customer? If so, you can specify a [trial_end](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=dotnet#create_subscription-trial_end) or [trial_period_days](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=dotnet#create_subscription-trial_period_days) when creating a subscription. Alternatively, you can also use a [coupon](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=dotnet#create_subscription-coupon) to apply discounts to invoices generated for this particular subscription.

Comment: Yes, I implemented the coupon already, the problem is that stripe does not accept zero charges. I want to add a free basic listing and a premium listing where I will charge using stripe.